# how do I continuously do a ps auxw on OSX?

Tags: terminal, ps

The question is this: If I open terminal and type `ps auxw`, I see a list of all processes running but this command is like a snapshot of that instant. What I need is this:

I am trying to discover what process is being run by an app that is crashing just after launching. I will use the finder and double click on the app icon to execute it. For a brief moment I know the app will launch and then crash.

How do I have a terminal window monitoring the running processes all the time, so when the app launches for a brief instant, that monitoring captures the process and lists it on terminal?

How do I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [macports](https://www.macports.org/) available (or possibly homebrew or a similar environment) you can use `watch` to print the output of the command every second:

```
 watch -n 1 ps auxw
```

An alternative is to use [glances](http://nicolargo.github.io/glances/), which is also available through macports.

Comment: @Mike careful though, at least on Linux, `watch` only monitors the visible output. See my question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101041/22222).

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use `watch` for this. Alternatives are

1. `top` and `htop`: these display processes in continuously updating windows.
2. Use the shell

   ```
   while true; do ps auxw; sleep 1; done
   ```
3. Use `strace` on Linux or [`ktrace`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ktrace-freebsd-macosx-tool-howto.html) on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

I used a modified command provided by @terdon:

```
while true; do ps auxw >> ps.txt; date >> ps.txt; sleep 1; done
```

I did this to make it easier to track the processes running at a given moment.